# char[4] to QColor Conversion

Tags: c++, qt, colors, qtgui, qcolor

I have a `char[4]` and I want to be able to cast it into a `QColor` is there a way that I can directly convert rather than doing this:

```
const char foo[4] = { 128, 128, 128, 128 };
const QColor bar( foo[0], foo[1], foo[2], foo[3] );
```

Comment: It looks like `QColor` has several overloaded constructors, one of which should do the trick for you `QColor ( const char * name )` ([see here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcolor.html))

Comment: What is wrong with this way?

Comment: A *"better way"* is very subjective, the question is unfit for stackoverflow since the answer would be *primarily opinion-based*. Please define what a *"better way"* would be like.

Comment: @Cyber I had looked at the `const char*` ctor, but it doesn't support an alpha channel. It is in fact looking for a string formatted color as described (here)[http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcolor.html#setNamedColor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that you are using RGBA, so you can use the corresponding constructor:

> [QColor::QColor(int r, int g, int b, int a = 255)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcolor.html#QColor-2)
>
> Constructs a color with the RGB value r, g, b, and the alpha-channel (transparency) value of a.
>
> The color is left invalid if any of the arguments are invalid.

You could also use the following static method:

> [QColor QColor::fromRgb(int r, int g, int b, int a = 255) [static]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcolor.html#fromRgb-2)
>
> Static convenience function that returns a QColor constructed from the RGB color values, r (red), g (green), b (blue), and a (alpha-channel, i.e. transparency).
>
> All the values must be in the range 0-255.

Comment: So individual element assignment, as in the original question, _is_ actually the most direct way to get from a `char[4]` to a `QColor`?

Comment: @JonathanMee: yes, there is no char* overridden version. That would not work for different rgba orders for instance.